# Where can I find Android: constant value in source code?

Tags: android, attributes, constants

I want to know there is a place to define all Android: named Constants and it's value.
Not html document in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:orientation

I means that where is source code in Android open source code repository for android:orientation and other attrs,such android:gravitiy.
I want to 0 means xx,and 1 means yy,but not from web site document.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find these as Java as they're built, just like R in your project.  You can see the xml definition of them in the SDK at android-sdk/platforms/android-#/data/res

For example, android.R.attr.orientation is found in android-sdk/platforms/android-#/res/values/attrs.xml and it's definition is the following for platform-16

```
<!-- Standard orientation constant. -->
<attr name="orientation">
    <!-- Defines an horizontal widget. -->
    <enum name="horizontal" value="0" />
    <!-- Defines a vertical widget. -->
    <enum name="vertical" value="1" />
</attr>
```

Answer (score 1):

What @Andy McSherry is saying is not entirely true, as often XML constants still need to be matched up in code (be it either Java or native) in order to perform logic with.

That being said, there is no single file that contains the definitions for all constants. In stead, constants are often defined relative to where they are being used. For example, the `android:orientation` values can be found in `LinearLayout` as [`LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#HORIZONTAL) (with value `0`) and [`LinearLayout.VERTICAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#VERTICAL) (with value `1`).

The possible values for `android:gravitiy` are actually defined in a separate class, [`Gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html), which makes sense from an encapsulation point of view, especially since gravities are used by different e.g. `ViewGroup` implementations.

Generally, as a rule of thumb, if constants are only relevant to a single class, you'll find them declared in that same class. Otherwise, it's likely they're factored out to a separate file or e.g. a superclass.